# Error while installing wine stable version

Tags: apt, package-management, xubuntu, wine, dependencies

I get the following error while trying to install wine:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 3.0.0~xenial)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Which release of Xubuntu?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

You can test with code in the cli:

1. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
2. `wget -qO - https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -`

   **Ubuntu 19.10:**
3. `sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/eoan main'`

   **Ubuntu 18.04:**

   `sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/bionic main'`

   and

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport`

4. `sudo apt update`
5. `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`

**In case of any errors:**

1. `sudo apt install aptitude`
2. `sudo aptitude install winehq-stable`